# Per day and per app time measuring in Google Family Link

Tags: google-family-link

Please, help me understand how Google Family Link is measuring time spent by my kid over a single application or per entire day.

My daughter has three devices (two of them are broken, during repair and not used, but still registered in Family Link). I have set a 2 hours daily-per-device limit, so she has 6 hours in total per day<sup>1</sup>. Yesterday late evening I found that she has 3 hours and 27 minutes left:

[image]

If my old-school math is still correct that means she has used **all her devices for 2 hours and 33 minutes** in total.

If that's true then what does this means:

[image]

How it is possible that she used all her devices for 2h 33m and in the same time she spent 6h 13 minutes in total? What I don't understand between these two screenshots?

And then this:

[image]

If she has **2 hours limit per device** (6 hours limit in total per 3 devices) how could she used YouTube on a single device for 5 hours?

Is this some kind of bug in Google Family Link that I have found? Or is this something wrong with my math (or my brain)?

<sup>1</sup> <sub>That's a business logic of Family Link. If you have two hours limit per device and spent zero minutes out of it on one of the devices, this entire limit is "transferred" to another device. And you can spend 4 hours there (even though limit is 2 hours per device). Weird like a hell, but that is how Family Link works.</sub>